# How to: safely call super constructors with different arguments

Tags: python, inheritance, init, superclass, diamond-problem

I have seen `super().__init__(*args)` used to call the super constructor safely (in a way that does not fail to diamond inheritence). However I cannot find a way to call different super constructors with different arguments in this way.

Here is an example illustraiting the problem.

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

X = TypeVar("X")
Y = TypeVar("Y")

class Base:
  def __init__(self):
    pass

class Left(Base, Generic[X]):
  def __init__(self, x:X):
    super().__init__()
    self.lft = x

class TopRight(Base, Generic[Y]):
  def __init__(self, y:Y):
    super().__init__()
    self.rgh = y

class BottomRight(TopRight[Y], Generic[Y]):
  def __init__(self, y:Y):
    super().__init__(y + y)

class Root(Left[X], BottomRight[Y], Generic[X, Y]):
  def __init__(self, x:X, y:Y):
    pass #issue here

    #does not work
    #super().__init__(x)
    #super().__init__(y)

    #calls base twice
    #Left[X].__init__(x)
    #BottomRight[Y].__init__(y)
```

How do I call `Left.__init__(x)` and `BottomRight.__init__(y)` seperately and safely?

Comment: For one things, `super().__init__()` calls in `Left` and `TopRight` are not OK since they don't respect even the signature of `Base`. You can either pass in an `int` or add a default parameter to `Base` to get past that issue.

Comment: I think the short answer is don't do stuff like this. There's a reason why something like Java doesn't support diamond inheritance.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that issue with the example code, also, multiple inheritence is still useful, especially considering pythons typing system.

Comment: Now `Base` has a syntax error in it (you forgot `pass`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that to be use in cooperative form, the intermediate classes have to accept the arguments that are not "aimed" at them, and pass those on on their own `super` call, in a way that becomes transparent.

You them **do not place multiple calls** to your ancestor classes: you let the language runtime do that for you.

Your code should be written:

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

X = TypeVar("X")
Y = TypeVar("Y")

class Base:
  def __init__(self):
      pass

class Left(Base, Generic[X]):
  def __init__(self, x:X, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)   
    self.lft = x

class TopRight(Base, Generic[Y]):
  def __init__(self, y:Y, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.rgh = y

class BottomRight(TopRight[Y], Generic[Y]):
  def __init__(self, y:Y, **kwargs):   # <- when this is executed, "y" is extracted from kwargs
    super().__init__(y=y + y, **kwargs)  # <-  "x" remains in kwargs, but this class does not have to care about it.

class Root(Left[X], BottomRight[Y], Generic[X, Y]):
  def __init__(self, x:X, y:Y):
      super().__init__(x=x, y=y)  # <- will traverse all superclasses,  "Generic" being last
```

Also, note that depending on your project's ends, and final complexity, these type annotations may gain you nothing, and instead, add complexity to a code otherwise trivial. They are not always a gain in Python projects, although due to circunstances the tooling (i.e. IDEs), might recommend them.

Also, check this similar answer from a few days ago, were I detail a bit more of Python method resolution order mechanisms, and point to the official documentation on them: [In multiple inheritance in Python, init of parent class A and B is done at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70269355/in-multiple-inheritance-in-python-init-of-parent-class-a-and-b-is-done-at-the-s/70296933#70296933)

Comment: Beat me to it. Very nice! Especially the last point. Duck typing is great most of the time.

Comment: Shouldn't call in `Root` be `super().__init__(x=x, y=y)`?

Comment: indeed. otherwise kwargs won't pick them

Comment: Also missing parens. `super()` vs `super`

Comment: @MadPhysicist I took the liberty of adding the parentheses